# UIImageView not displaying new image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have an image cache class, which downloads icons if necessary and caches them. In my view controller, in viewDidAppear, I have:

```
// (showIcon is a UIImageView from the storyboard)
showIcon.image = [[LRImageCache imageCache] imageForURL:iconURL completionTarget:self action:@selector(updateImage:)];
```

If the image is already cached, it is returned here, and is correctly displayed. Otherwise, a placeholder image is returned, and the cache class attempts to download the image. When (if) successful, it calls the target/action:

```
- (void)updateImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    showIcon.image = image;
}
```

Setting a breakpoint on that line confirms that 'image' is the correct, downloaded image - but it doesn't display!

I can't help but think I'm missing something really obvious...

Comment: Is the showIcon imageview connected in your connections inspector?

Comment: `showIcon` is probably `nil`. When you debug the `image` can you also check the value of `showIcon`?

Comment: `showIcon` is connected. I've just double-checked, and it isn't `nil` - it has the same address (as you'd expect, being an instance variable!) as it did during the successful assignment in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `updateImage:` which is expecting an argument, with your code you call the method but you don't provide the argument.

Consider creating an image object first like so:

```
UIImage *myImage =  [[LRImageCache imageCache] imageForURL:iconURL completionTarget:self action:@selector(updateImage)];
```

Remove the argument from the updateImage method (remember to remove the colon from the selector when setting the image.

```
- (void)updateImage{
    showIcon.image = myImage;
}
```

Comment: `updateImage` is called by the `imageCache` class (which I haven't shown code for). It does provide an argument, and when debugging I can see that that argument is the expected image with the 'quick preview' in XCode. Just to test, I created a new `UIImageView` within that `updateImage` method, assigned the passed `image` to it and added it to the main view - the image is displayed correctly.

Comment: Try adding an NSLog to the updateImage method to see if it is being called.